# Connecting to Mandrill through a proxy with Laravel

Tags: laravel, proxy, swiftmailer, mandrill

I'm using Laravel (4.2) to send emails in my application. Locally this works fine however when I upload to our internal server I get

```
Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established
```

It's running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and we have XAMPP v3.2.1 installed

We use a proxy but I have no idea how I can route my application through it.

Can anyone give me some suggestions please?

Comment: check your connection data string.

Comment: I have the same problem and I have found zero answers here. Kind of amazing.